# Sails configuration based on brand

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Is there a way to have Sails load configuration based on environment AND brand?

Here's an example:

`/config/env/<brand-name>/<environment-name>.js`

`<brand-name>` will be specified in environment variables as well just like `<environment-name>`

If there isn't a way to do this out-of-the-box, is there any best practice to handle such use case?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several things you can do, and here is one - in your environment js file require a configuration js file, the path to which is based on the brand environment variavble, and then merge it with the current configuration. Your brand configuration file can be anywhere as long as you can assemble the path to it based on the value of the brand environment variable. Should be pretty straightforward. That way you can have brand configurations for all the environments you set. Currently I am not in front of a computer, so I am posting this solution with no code.